# ASP.NET 3.5 + System.Web.Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, url-routing, asp.net-routing

I have downloaded sample from [here](http://go2.wordpress.com/?id=725X1342&site=chriscavanagh.wordpress.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chriscavanagh.com%2Fchris%2Fsource%2FSimpleRoutingTest.zip&sref=http%3A%2F%2Fchriscavanagh.wordpress.com%2F2008%2F10%2F18%2Faspnet-routing-revisited-again%2F) ([Demo](http://www.chriscavanagh.com/Chris/SimpleRoutingTest/anything))but when i deploy it on my **Godady** server it gives me error

```
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

Can any one tell me what's wrong with **Godady**. This sample work fine on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote to Godady but confused what to ask them now....

**Support Staff Response**

> Thank you for contacting Online
> Support.
>
> This looks like a trust issue.Trust
> level refers to permissions set in the
> Web.config file that dictate what
> operations can and cannot be performed
> by Web applications. Our ASP.NET 3.5
> shared hosting servers use the default
> Medium trust level with the addition
> of OleDbPermission, OdbcPermission,
> and a less-restrictive WebPermission.
> Applications operating under a Medium
> trust level have no registry access,
> no access to the Windows event log,
> and cannot use ReflectionPermission
> (but can use Reflection). Such
> applications can communicate only with
> a defined range of network addresses
> and file system access is limited to
> the application's virtual directory
> hierarchy.
>
> Using a Medium trust level prevents
> applications from accessing shared
> system resources and eliminates the
> potential for application
> interference. Adding OleDbPermission
> and OdbcPermission allows applications
> to use those data providers to access
> databases. WebPermission is modified
> to allow outbound http and https
> traffic.
>
> Please let us know if we can assist
> you in any other way.

**Customer Inquiry**

> I have uploaded my site
> (http://www.pinchofbliss.com/anything)
>
> but i get error :
>
> ======================================================================
>
> Description: The application attempted
> to perform an operation not allowed by
> the security policy. To grant this
> application the required permission
> please contact your system
> administrator or change the
> application's trust level in the
> configuration file.
>
> Exception Details:
> System.Security.SecurityException:
> Request for the permission of type
> 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
> mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral
>
> ========================================================================
>
> For more detail let me write more that
> this sample application working fine
> on local machine even i placed
> application with source code this
> sample application can be downloaded
> from here
> http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/